# :( rejects "" minutes timed out while waiting for input to be rejected" shows when checking my proggram

Tags: c, cs50

The program shows the correct infor when I compile it or run it.
The problem is when I check the program. It shows ":( rejects "" minutes 
timed out while waiting for input to be rejected" when checking my 
proggram. I tried using `GetInt` and `get_int`as well. Can you help me, 
please?

```
int main(void)
{
    int Minutes,Bottles;

    printf("Minutes: ");
    scanf("%d", &Minutes);
    Bottles = Minutes * 12;
    printf("Bottles: %d\n", Bottles);

}
```

Comment: "*The problem is when I check the program.*", how exactly are you doing that? And what are `GetInt` and/or `get_int`?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by checking the program?

Comment: are you using some kind of on-line platform like codechef?

Comment: The posted code works perfectly well, after adding `#include <stdio.h>` and assuming you don't make a mistake in the data entry. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: By "*assuming you don't make a mistake with the data entry*" @WeatherVane means that you should have checked the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi yes I did, but if this is an online challenge submission, there is no possible recovery strategy from a bad input, which is typically supplied to `stdin` by redirection, and the input is taken as "good".

Comment: -Iharob Al Asimi- I check the program through CS50 IDE, by entering check50 cs50/2017/x/water  and this is what it shows :  :( rejects "" minutes
timed out while waiting for input to be rejected 

Log 
running ./water... 
sending input ... 
checking that input was rejected...

Comment: -Jean-Francois Fabre- I am using  "CS50 IDE"

Comment: -Rajeev Ranjan-  What I mean by checking the program is that, since I know that the program works accordingly, I enter:   check50 cs50/2017/x/water and there is where i get the problem which reads :  :( rejects "" minutes
timed out while waiting for input to be rejected 

Log 
running ./water... 
sending input ... 
checking that input was rejected...

Comment: This is the link to the results of the code I am having the problem with  https://cs50.me/checks/585e64977075aafd69d9722dac03d0a1c23722a6

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to complete the CS50 problem set named water, you need to include the header file `cs50.h` and use the `GetInt()` function in order to pass the checks. If you see the lectures(again), the instructor mentions that this function is written in such a way that it accepts only integer values.

The mistake you make is not accounting for any input other than integer. Use this function like

```
Minutes = GetInt();
```

instead of

```
scanf("%d", &Minutes);
```